# How do I get a specific result in datatables?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

Ok, I want to get info of all tigersand owner that have the same OwnerID (Tigerinfo) as MemberID (Memberinfo)....

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Medleminfo.MemberId, 
Medleminfo.Förnamn, Medleminfo.Efternamn,Medleminfo.Adress, 
Medleminfo.Telefon, Tigerinfo.Tigernamn,Tigerinfo.Födelsedatum FROM Medleminfo, Tigerinfo WHERE Medleminfo.MemberId = Tigerinfo.OwnerID ";
```

As it is now I get ALL info, I just wanna compare it to MAX(Medleminfo.MemberId)

How can I redefine it?

Comment: Huh?  Do not understand.  Please show tables with sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer this because I know what you are looking for from your previous post.  Though in the future, you should REALLY post data structures, code blocks, expected output etc.  If you want to only get ONE record based on the max id, I would change your query to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT Medleminfo.MemberId, 
Medleminfo.Förnamn, Medleminfo.Efternamn,Medleminfo.Adress, 
Medleminfo.Telefon, Tigerinfo.Tigernamn,Tigerinfo.Födelsedatum FROM Medleminfo JOIN Tigerinfo ON Medleminfo.MemberId = Tigerinfo.OwnerID WHERE Medleminfo.MemberId = (SELECT MAX(MemberId) FROM Medleminfo) ";
```

This is called a SQL subquery check out this link for more information on subqueries:

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm

Comment: Thank you iMortalitySX, I really appreciate it :)